# How to init a string with attributes in swift?

Tags: swift, osx-yosemite

I want to init a string with some properties, but I receive this error :

```
"Canot invoke "init" with an argument list of type '(string: @value String, attributes: $T8)
```

Here is my code : 
Update:

```
var myColor: NSColor = NSColor.greenColor()
vat myStr = "content"


  let string = NSAttributedString(string: myStr, attributes: [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: myColor,
                NSKernAttributeName: -2,
                NSFontAttributeName: myFont])
```

Does anyone have any idea why ?

Comment: Give us more detail like how you declare myStr, myColor, and myFont.because with this code I didn't get any error.

Comment: What is your Xcode version?

Comment: I use Xcode 6.1, and this is an OS X app.

Comment: @C-Viorel: You haven't yet shown how myFont is defined.

Comment: You have right ! I found the problem . Var "myFont" was not correct .   "let font = NSFont(name: currentFont, size: currentSize) " I forget to add "?? NSFont.labelFontOfSize(14)" at the end .